# iAds with new iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, ios8, iad, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

As well as the [iAd Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH1-SW1) is outdated since a long time (it proposes code samples which are deprecated since iOS6).

I wonder what to do in order to **display an Ad properly with the new iPhone6 and 6+ native resolution**.

It seems that Apple didn't do anything about it and that banners always display themselves with 50pt of height whatever size you give the banner. (Which result as white strips on the ad)

If anyone know a solution or have a technical/release note that talk about it ?

**Edit:**
On iAd WorkBench a news appears about it :

> iPhone 6 and 6 Plus
>
> All existing campaigns targeting iPhones will now include iPhone 6 and
>   6 Plus, together with iPhone 4s, 5, 5c, and 5s, and iPod touch 4th and
>   5th generation and earlier. Existing ads will run in letterboxes to
>   accommodate the longer widths, until you upload iPhone 6 and 6 Plus
>   assets. Ads created using banner templates will auto-convert to
>   support all iPhone devices including iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.
>
> iPhone 6 and 6 Plus assets are required for any new or edited
>   campaigns targeting iPhone users. You can now bulk-upload assets for
>   all iOS devices.
>
> Updated iAd Workbench Creative Specifications, including
>   specifications for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus as well as audio ads, are
>   available for download.
>
> An update to iAd Tester v5.0 is now available, and must be used to preview ads correctly on iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

For my iAds ads, I use the banner size parameter *Smart portrait* :

```
[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait]
```

It works well for me on iPhone 4,5,6 and 6+  and also with the iPads.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not exactly related. `GADBannerView` is for Admob ads. Question about iAd. Now if Admob  supports more sizes than Apple's iAd itself then that's still useful information.